# Payment from this device are not allowed - Android Paypal

Tags: android, paypal

I have integrated paypal sdk in my app some devices it redirects paypal payment page and works fine, but some devices it showing **"Payment from this device are not allowed"**

Comment: are you using sandbox environment or live environment? please ensure you use the right client ID credentials for each environment.

Comment: i am using live environment and added correct client id. it works fine in some devices

Comment: can you add the logcat associated with the error shown?

Answer (score 0):

In the rarest case you might have missed the code correction of create Order.
Apart from that PayPal itself have blocked your current IP location. Restart your System. It will automatically get allocated a new IP. And it will definitely start to work.